# android 4.0.3 and jquery compatibility

Tags: android, jquery

I'm currently developing an Android application who uses a WebView loading html/js pages.

These pages are games developed with jQuery, especially to make animations.

I have an issue on Android 4.0.3 . I can't get animations to work correctly. But the weird thing is that it works on Nexus S and not on a Sony tablet. Both run Android 4.0.3 and the same application with the same code.

I tried to use jQuery mobile but it doesn't work

What do you think about that ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue at the jQuery-camp:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquerymobile-1-0-does-not-support-android-4-0-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: Yes but it's very annoying.. i can't find a way to fix it